# How to pass dynamic amount of arguments in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, arguments, sails.js

I try to pass different amount of arguments in different cases.
I have the next code:

```
function getByteCode(tokenData, incomeData){

        incomeData.volume = Number(incomeData.volume) * Math.pow(10,tokenData.decimals);
        incomeData.volume = incomeData.volume.noExponents();
        let web3 = new Web3();
        let instanceContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
        instanceContract.options.address = tokenData.address;
        let necessaryMethod = instanceContract.methods[incomeData.methodCall];
        let methodCall = necessaryMethod(incomeData.destination_address, incomeData.volume);
        return methodCall.encodeABI();
    } catch (err) {
        sails.log(err);
        return {
            state: 'fail',
            message: 'There is error in creation byte code \n' + err
        }
    } 
}
```

In **necessaryMethod** I want to pass two arguments in one case and pass three or more argument in other case. How can I do it? Maybe I should use "[arguments](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)", but I don`t understand how?

Comment: You can put the arguments in an array and then use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: It's unclear from the code what are these 'one case' and 'other case'.

Comment: @Pointy no need to use .apply, the spread operator will achieve the same an be clearer. necessaryMethod(...array)

Comment: @sofcal I'm old-school :) Also `...` is not an operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, tank you for the helping. I have used method .apply()

```
let web3 = new Web3();
let instanceContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
instanceContract.options.address = tokenData.address;
let necessaryMethod = instanceContract.methods[incomeData.methodCall];

let methodCall = necessaryMethod.apply(this, incomeData.argumentsForFunction); 

return methodCall.encodeABI();
```

In first case I called function **getByteCode(firstObj, incomeData)** and there is next array in incomeData.argumentsForFunction = ['0x323.....', '1500000000'].

In other case I called function **getByteCode(firstObj, incomeData)** with incomeData.argumentsForFunction = ['0x323.....', '0x3228....', '54454000000']